# inputView and inputAccessoryView prior to 3.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I'm trying to add support for 3.1.3, as it's the last version on the first generation iPods. I
was wondering how to simulate the inputView and inputAccessoryView for a UITextField prior to 3.2, as those have been added only in 3.2 afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial, might be helpful.

http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/adding-a-toolbar-with-next-previous-above-uitextfield-keyboard-iphone/

I have used this to create a toolbar with NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons and support iOS 3.1.3 as well.